# how to print out panda dataframes in vscode

Tags: pandas, visual-studio-code

In a terminal, i can print out the value of a `dataframe` and it prints out in a readable way

[image]

Where as in vscode, when running in a debugger, it prints out as one long row and is hard to read.

[image]

any suggestions on how to make it more readable on vscode?

Comment: How about PyCharm?

Comment: Don't running in a debugger, use Code Runner(an extension) to run it.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Changing the terminal of VScode to 'git bash' in the terminal tab. It has worked for me.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 6):

I ended up using the vscode `Python:Terminal (external)`, and within the debug environment, I can do a `print(df)`  which reads nicely within the terminal.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, can you please  share your steps to resolve this issue .Thanks